# Jquery copy text to Clipboard when input field is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy the content of input field in the clipboard

My code is

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs copy-link" title="Copy Link"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>
<input type="text" class="link" value="Hello World">

<script>
    $(document).on('click','.copy-link', function() {
        var copyText = $(this).siblings('.link');
        copyText.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.val());
    });
</script>
```

this code is working fine...

But I want input field hidden. Like

```
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs copy-link" title="Copy Link"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>
<input type="hidden" class="link" value="Hello World" />
```

Then the value is not coping with the same jquery...

Is there anything else that I'm missing.?

Comment: Did you try using `<input type='text' style='display:none'>`?

Comment: yes... I've tried it

Comment: What about `<input type='text' style='position:absolute; top:-50px; opacity:0'>`?

Comment: @Psi It works... Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can put your link into a link attribute in your button,

I suggest you the following:

- Remove your `input` from the HTML
- Create it directly in the function

Here is a working snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.copy-link', function() {
  var link = $(this).attr('link');
  var tempInput = document.createElement("input");
  tempInput.style = "position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px";
  tempInput.value = link;
  document.body.appendChild(tempInput);
  tempInput.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log("Copied the text:", tempInput.value);
  document.body.removeChild(tempInput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs copy-link" title="Copy Link" link="Hello World"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

try opacity 0 ; 
here it work for sure ;)

```
<input type="text" class="link hidden" value="Hello World 2">
.hidden {
  position:absolute; top:-50px; opacity:0;
}
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/47741/

Comment: This will leave the space for the input. You'll end up with an empty space where the input would be displayed if it wasn't faded out.

Comment: better to use `position: absolute` and `left: 9999px`

Comment: Then adding some css property like position : absolute and move it right/left will be ok

Answer (score 0):

Apply the style mentioned below and then use the same jquery code. It will work.

```
<input type="text" class="link hidden" value="Hello World 2" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px;">
```

Comment: I don't recommend setting `top` since focusing the element may result into page scrolling

Comment: ok, I removed that. But the basic solution to mention here is to set CSS which can hide from frontpage and also make it accessible to jquery code.